# Multiple labels in a list item

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to have more than 1 labelfield in my list it is currently pulling from a database below is my code:

```
<s:List id="list2" includeIn="hurlingprofile" x="0" y="63" width="480" height="687"
        color="#000000"     creationComplete="list2_creationCompleteHandler(event)" labelField="Name">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllProfilehurlingResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
```

I have it shown all names but i need to show all date of births.

I tried adding labels through the design view but they only one name not all names in the list. How can I add a label that will show in each list item.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can take:

1. Use a `DataGrid` if you want to have multiple columns
2. Use an inline or separate `itemRenderer`
3. Use the `itemRendererFunction` property of `List`

For your use, I guess the inline `itemRenderer` will be good.

Comment: If you don't mind a single line of text, you can use the labelFunction on the List to format the label string to your needs.  Otherwise, for a more complicated display the itemRenderer would be required.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's a flex mobile project that I'm creating so dataGrid won't work as it is discouraged.

Comment: its discouraged but i use (spark) DataGrids on mobile without issues.

Comment: ...however, DataGrid would be overkill for your needs - use labelFunction if you can, otherwise an ItemRenderer